# How do I remove the focus shadows from a UIView in a UICollectionView in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, tvos

I'm working on a tvOS project in swift and have a horizontally aligned `UICollectionView` where each `UICollectionViewCell` is a custom UIView consisting of a `UIImageView` and a `Label` below it. So my UICollectionView looks like this:

```
| UIImageView |   | UIImageView |
| Label       |   | Label       |
```

I also wanted the image to grow/shrink as the particular view gained and lost focus. In my collection view I added the code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
}
```

And in my custom cell class I have the line

```
imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true;
```

So this somewhat works, although with 2 problems.

It seems all the views in the collection have a weird shadow under them, even when they're not focused. And then when they are focused, the image grows as expected, but it has another shadow under it. You can see what I mean here:

[image: this screenshot]

The first item in the collection has the focus

How do I get rid of them? I've tried all of these but none of them seem to work

```
contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0  // My imageView is a subview of this
contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

Comment: Did you found a solution yet? Struggling with the same problem ATM

Comment: No :(
I ended up setting imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = false and manually styling the look of it when it's focused as opposed to using the default styling when that's true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible right now. I forwarded this question to Apple, and the response was: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/105045#105045

Comment: Well that wraps this up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for UITableViewCell and CollectionViewCell:

```
self.clipToBounds = true

self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

This is if you needed to restore rounded edges.